# How to compare two (vague) file lists and print the duplicates?

Tags: bash, uniq

I have two file lists. `backup.txt` and `backup2.txt`
Some of the entries aren't exact, so it makes it difficult to find the duplicates with `diff` or `uniq`.

Example:

```
:::backup.txt:::
auser_backup
auser_backup2
buser_backup
cuser_backup

:::backup2.txt:::
auser.backup
auser.backup.2
buser
cuser
```

I was wondering if there is a way to compare these vaguely similar file lists, where `auser_backup` and `auser.backup` along with `auser_backup2` and `auser.backup.2` would be counted as duplicates.

Maybe there's another step to rename all the entries so that the formats are correct? I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: You mean *all four* starting with `auser` seen as one duplicate (well, "quadroplicate")?

Comment: And what about `buser_backup` and `buser`, are those dups?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to pre-process the files to "fix" the irregularities:

```
fixfile() { sed -r 's/([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]]+)$/\1.\2/; s/\./_/g' "$1"; }
comm -12 <(fixfile backup.txt | sort) <(fixfile backup2.txt | sort)
```

```
auser_backup
auser_backup_2
```

Comment: That is neat, avoids lots of while loop.